# Concurrent create in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, consistency, nosql

Due to some vague reasons we are using replicated orient-db for our application.

It looks likely that we will have cases when a single record could be created twice. Here is how it happens:

- we have entities `user_document`, they have ID of user and ID of document - both users and documents are managed in another application and stored in another database;
- this another application on creating new document sends broadcast event (via rabbit-mq topic);
- several instances of our application receive this message and create another `user_document` with the same pair of `user_id` and `document_id`.

If I understand correct, we should use `UNIQUE` index on the pair of these ids and rely upon distributed transactions.

However due to some reasons (we have another team writitng layer between application and database) we probably could not use `UNIQUE` though it may sound stupid :)

What are our chances then?

Could we, for example, allow all instances to create redundant records and immediately after creation select by `user_id` and `document_id` and if more than one were found, delete ones with lexicografically higher own `id`?

Comment: What release are you using? Please upgrade to 1.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do in that way.
You can try to use something like

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT FROM user_document where user_id=? and document_id=? skip 1)
```

However, take a notice that without creation of index this approach may consume some additional resources on server, and you might got a significant slow down if *user_document* have big amount of records.